# Does the System logger use computer resources?

Tags: java, logging, applet, systemtime

I want to launch an applet with sandbox permissions but it accesses System time and I has a system logger which am not sure can run in a protected view.

Comment: _"..which am not sure can run in a protected view"_ I'm not sure what is it, but can't you just try it?

Answer (score 1):

A sand-boxed applet can access [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

A sand-boxed applet can only access an anonymous logger (i.e. **not** a named logger) as might be obtained from [`Logger.getAnonymousLogger()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getAnonymousLogger%28%29).  I doubt most 3rd party APIs would have the ability to create an anonymous logger, as they are usually used in apps. with all-permissions or no security manager.  Either way, the logger for a sand-boxed applet cannot dump the log to a place that would not be permitted in a sand box (e.g. `File` or a printer).